# pcsc-sharp unable to send apdu command with the newest build (6.0)

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu

I am using https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp to send APDU commands to a smart card. Now if I use 3.8 version and do this:

```
  var iSSecureElement = false;

  IsoReader reader = GetReader(ref iSSecureElement);

  var responseSCard = reader.Transmit(new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case3Short, reader.ActiveProtocol)
  {
    CLA = 0x88,
    INS = 0x11,
    P1 = 0x04,
    P2 = 0x00,
    Data = GetIntArray(3151)
  });

  Assert.AreEqual(responseSCard.SW1, (byte)SW1Code.Normal);
```

it works, I get responseSCard.SW1 = 144 (Normal), but if I do this with the latest version (6.0):

```
public static string PINVerify(string reader_, int PIN_)
{
  using (var ctx = ContextFactory.Instance.Establish(SCardScope.System))
  {
    using (ICardReader isoReader = ctx.ConnectReader(reader_, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any))
    {

      CommandApdu apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case3Short, isoReader.Protocol)
      {
        CLA = 0x88,
        INS = 0x11,
        P1 = 0x04,
        P2 = 0x00,
        Data = Utils.GetIntArray(PIN_)
      };

      return getResult(isoReader, apdu);

    }
  }

}

private static string getResult(ICardReader isoReader, CommandApdu apdu)
{
  using (isoReader.Transaction(SCardReaderDisposition.Leave))
  {
    var sendPci = SCardPCI.GetPci(isoReader.Protocol);
    var receivePci = new SCardPCI(); // IO returned protocol control information.

    var receiveBuffer = new byte[256];
    var command = apdu.ToArray();

    var bytesReceived = isoReader.Transmit(
        sendPci, // Protocol Control Information (T0, T1 or Raw)
        command, // command APDU
        command.Length,
        receivePci, // returning Protocol Control Information
        receiveBuffer,
        receiveBuffer.Length); // data buffer

    var responseApdu = new ResponseApdu(receiveBuffer, bytesReceived, IsoCase.Case2Short, isoReader.Protocol);

    return string.Format("SW1: {0:X2}, SW2: {1:X2} Uid: {2}",
        responseApdu.SW1,
        responseApdu.SW2,
        responseApdu.HasData ? BitConverter.ToString(responseApdu.GetData()) : "No uid received");
  }
}
```

it doesn't work, I get responseApdu.SW1 = 104 (ErrorFunctionNotSupported). Actually with the newest version of it I can't get anything working, always is the same response. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  Changing version of library requires recompiling all the code.

Comment: yes, I already did it, clean, rebuild, restart VS, restart laptop  and nothing, something else is causing this, but I cant figure out what

Comment: Best way to start is to access smart card with window explorer and try accessing the card.  If windows explorer doesn't work than the driver has an issue and you need to update driver.  The smart card first gets unlocked which windows will do and then stays unlocked until powered off.  So often I find you can unlock card with windows (file explorer) and then run app.   But if you just run app it fails.  This is clue that card isn't getting unlocked in application.  You also may need a certificate to unlock and using File Explorer will give error message.

Comment: sure, it is available, look I have 2 c# projects. Project 1 has pcsc-sharp ver 6 and reference project 2 (DLL) which has version 3.8. When I use functions from old pcsc-sharp ver 3.8 it always works - accessing card successfully, but the code that uses ver 6 doesn't, not even with the same APDU commands, so something else is the problem

Comment: look, I can always fail back to the old software, but that is not the point

Comment: The new software may be accessing the card in a different mode and the driver may be old and doesn't work with the new option.  Smart cards there are lots of different modes and driver may not support the mode with new version of software.  Make sure you can read/write with File Explorer and notepad.  If windows is working than it is an issue between software and driver.

Comment: Make sure you use the vendors driver and not the generic windows driver.  Windows generic drivers do not always work with devices in every mode.